# How can I prevent YouTube from distorting the audio in my QuickTime video?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, youtube, quicktime

I recorded about 20 MP4 clips: most on my Android phone with the stock camera, a couple from Facebook (downloaded from the mobile web view), and one from a Zoom session. I cropped or scaled and padded the FB and Zoom clips with ffmpeg to match the clips from my phone (vertical 1080p). I trimmed all the clips in the Mac QuickTime player, which exported .m4v. I then combined the clips into a single video with the QuickTime player, which saved .mov.

The .mov video looks and sounds as it should throughout. However, when I upload the .mov video to YouTube

the result has two audio problems:

- The audio in the clips immediately before the Zoom clip and one of the FB clips is lowered in pitch. The preceding, distorted clips start at 1:08:18 and 41:01 respectively.
- The audio in the Zoom clip is really distorted, almost gone, partway through, at 1:11:21.

(The clip at 6:18 doesn't seem to have been distorted by the clip from FB which follows it. The FB clip that doesn't cause the problem is from the FB Live Android app; I think the one that does is from the Acapella app, but I didn't make it so I'm not sure.)

The problems are much worse in the Zoom clip and the clip that precedes it, which are the second- and third-to-last clips in the video, so I worked around the problem by posting a video including only the last 3 clips. The audio in that video is fine throughout!?!

**How can I adjust my clips so that YouTube preserves the audio in the full-length video?**

Side note: I found that converting the .mov video to .mp4 with a recent ffmpeg snapshot causes the exact same problems in the result, so, if we knew what to do to get a good result with ffmpeg, that might fix the problem on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that different clips had different frame rates. My phone records a variable frame rate around 30 fps, the Zoom video had a fixed frame rate of 25 fps, the FB live video was variable around 30 fps and the Acapella-via-FB video was fixed 30 fps. I fixed the problem by reencoding all clips to a fixed frame rate of 30 fps with `ffmpeg -r 30`. (I also set a minimum audio bitrate of 96 kb/s, the bitrate of most of the original footage, with `-b:v 96k`. ffmpeg defaulted to an audio bitrate of 69 kb/s.)

The QuickTime player refused to concatenate the frame-rate-adjusted clips, so I concatenated the clips in batches of 32 with [ffmpeg's concat filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec) and then concatenated the result of that with [ffmpeg's more efficient concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer). (Concatenating in one pass with ffmpeg's concat demuxer dropped the audio entirely from some scenes; I didn't take the time to figure out why.) I was able to combine frame rate adjustment and batch concatenation into one ffmpeg command, i.e. one reencoding step.